# ViewScoped bean rebuilt when FileUploadListener called using PrettyFaces

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I've inserted a `<p:fileUpload />` component into my **JSF 2.1.5** application. I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.4.1**. This component is backed by a `@ViewScoped` bean. I have my form in this way:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/templates/general_template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>

        <f:viewParam id="NavIndex" name="NavIndex"
            value="#{navegableMassiveUserAdd._QueueIndex}" />
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{navegableMassiveUserAdd.initialize}" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="general_content">
    <h:form>

        <p:fileUpload
            fileUploadListener="#{navegableMassiveUserAdd.listener}"
            mode="advanced" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|csv)$/"
            label="#{msg.SELECT}" multiple="false" />

        <p:commandButton id="cancelButton"
            action="#{navegableMassiveUserAdd.actionCancelAdd}"
            value="#{msg.CANCELAR}" ajax="false" style="margin: 9px 0px 5px;" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Here it is my main template:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="-1"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="prime_styles.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="prime_translations.js" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:insert name="metadata" />
    <ui:insert name="general_logged_user">
        <div align="right">
            <span style="color: #B22222; padding: 3px;"> <h:outputText
                    value="#{loggedBean._Login}" />
            </span> <span style="color: #FFA54F; padding: 3px;"> <h:outputText
                    value="Auth Method: #{loggedBean._Usuario._CUser._AuthenticationMethod}" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </ui:insert>
    <f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}">
        <ui:insert name="general_settings">
            <f:loadBundle basename="resources.system.bundles.Messages" var="msg" />
            <p:ajaxStatus style="width:0px;height:0px;" id="ajaxStatusPanel"
                styleClass="spinner_ajax_loading">

                <f:facet name="start">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/loading.gif" />
                </f:facet>

                <f:facet name="complete">
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:ajaxStatus>
            <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
        </ui:insert>

        <f:event type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{navigationManagerSystem.initialize}" />


        <h:panelGroup>
            <ui:insert name="general_header">
                <ui:include src="/components/header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            <h:panelGroup id="menuNavegacionPanel">

                <h:form>
                    <h:panelGroup id="navigationPanel"
                        rendered="#{navigationManagerSystem._ShowNavegacion}">
                        <h:panelGroup
                            rendered="#{!navigationManager._DisableNavigationButtons}">
                            <p:toolbar>
                                <p:toolbarGroup>
                                    <ui:repeat value="#{navigationManagerSystem._Navegables}"
                                        var="item">
                                        <p:button value="#{item._Title}"
                                            outcome="#{item._NavigationResult}">
                                            <f:param name="NavIndex" value="#{item._QueueIndex}" />
                                        </p:button>
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                    <p:button disabled="true"
                                        value="#{navigationManagerSystem._Navegable._Title}" />
                                </p:toolbarGroup>
                            </p:toolbar>
                        </h:panelGroup>

                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <ui:insert name="general_content">
                <ui:include src="/system/content.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>

        </h:panelGroup>
        <ui:insert name="general_footer">

            <ui:include src="/components/general_footer.xhtml" />

        </ui:insert>
    </f:view>

</h:body>
```

With that, when I upload my file, the bean is being rebuilt and the `listener` method not being called. I have the filters put in my *web.xml*. Also if I change my form and set it as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, as I read in documentation, I can't avoid the problem and the bean is rebuilt again, in this case even when I click on the cancel button. That's my bean code, where `SystemNavegable` is an abstract class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NavegableMassiveUserAdd extends SystemNavegable {

/**
 * Field logger.
 */
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

/**
 * Constructor for NavegableMassiveUserAdd.
 */
public NavegableMassiveUserAdd() {
    super();
    this.set_Title(FacesUtils.getBundle(BundleNames.BUNDLE_SYSTEM_MENU,
            BundleKeys.SYSTEM_NAVEGABLE_ADD_USERS, "Añadir usuarios"));
    this.set_TitleDescription(FacesUtils.getBundle(BundleNames.BUNDLE_SYSTEM_MENU,
            BundleKeys.SYSTEM_NAVEGABLE_ADD_USERS_DESCRIPTION, "Añadir usuarios"));
    this.set_NavigationResult(NavigationResults.MASSIVE_USER_ADD);
    this._Behaviour = NavegableBehaviour.ADD;
}
/**
 * Method actionCancelAdd.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String actionCancelAdd() {
    return this._NavigationManagerSystem.cancelNavegable();
}

/**
 * Escuchador del evento Upload.
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * @param event
 *            FileUploadEvent
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    UploadedFile uploadItem = event.getFile();
    //More code
    }
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

More tests done and I found that the file upload listener method is never reached, it doesn't matter which Scope I give to the backing bean. I have following dependencies included:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I suspect the problem can be there's another filter conflicting with the one I have for the upload component, [as is told here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4390313/1199132). Whatever the problem is, my bean's initialize method is being called again when file is uploaded and `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()` comes with false.

Comment: I see that you are using some template (general_template.xhtml). Can you put its code?

Comment: Why do you say enctype is wrong? Whatever it happens does not generate an ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several brainstorming, I found it's a filter problem. Because of upload filters are in conflict with [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) filters, I had to add this to my *web.xml*:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Many thanks @Reinaldo de Carvalho for this response

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086137/1199132

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in Tomcat server POST size limit.
So, after parameter maxPostSize of Connector section in server.xml has been set
file upload start to work great with @ViewScoped bean.

Also notice that tomcat official documentation is incorrect and for unlimited size of POST maxPostSize value must be set less then 0, because when it`s equals 0 means zero size.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html
[HttpRequest maximum allowable size in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat)