# Primefaces growl not visible after file upload event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, growl

I have simple page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body id="background" bgcolor="#F9F9F9">

<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUpload.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                  update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />    
</h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

the `<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>` is not visible when any file uploaded, i am using like `http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf`
consol shows an exception

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setIntHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

thanks

Comment: Event is not captured in fileUpload.handleFileUpload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my problem by adding

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388441/primefaces-fileupload-event-not-firing-jsf-2-0)